# multiprocessing python

Tags: python

Нужно написать код мультипроцессинга для двух функций, в одной мы вводим значения старта и конца (например `0 5`), и вводим имена (`Паша Женя Ваня`). Вторая функция (`set`) печатает результат. Аргументы написанные внутри функции, обязательны.
На выходе надо получить следующее:
Паша 0
Женя 1
Ваня 2
Паша 3
Женя 4
Ваня 5

Нужно использовать `Process`, `Lock`, `Value`. Ниже есть код, я смог только реализовать последовательный счетчик для одной функции. Как соединить его с именами и вывести, я не могу понять.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock,Value

start = Value('I',0)

def set(name,item,iter_stop,lock):
    """
    Prints out the item that was passed in
    """
    with start.get_lock():
      start.value+=1
      print(start.value,name)
def start_g():
  start, game_stop = map(int, input().split()) 
  players = input().split()
  set

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    lst=['Паша', 'Женя','Ваня']
    for item in lst:
        p = Process(target=start_g, args=(item, lock))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Еще есть код функции без использования мультипроцессинга.

```
   def start_game():
        start, game_stop = map(int, input().split()) 
        players = input().split()  
        a=start
        lst=[]
        while a!=game_stop+1:
            for i in players:
                lst.append(i)
                a=a+1
                if a==game_stop+1:
                    break
        for name,current_step in list(zip(lst,range(start,game_stop+1))):
          print(f'{name}: {current_step}')
```

Comment: вы его запускать пробовали?

Comment: он естественно нерабочий

Answer (score 1):

Вот, держите работающий код. Если неправильно вас понял, допилите

Можете players положить в разделяемый Array

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock,Value

def set(players, value):
    """
    Prints out the item that was passed in
    """
    with value.get_lock():
      print(value.value, players[value.value % len(players)])
      value.value += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # start, game_stop = map(int, input().split())
    start, game_stop = 0, 6
    # players = input().split()
    players = ['Паша', 'Женя','Ваня']
    value = Value('I', start)
    processes = [Process(target=set, args=(players,  value)) for i in range(start, game_stop+1)]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
    for process in processes:
        process.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но боюсь мне нужно было другое, требуется две функции, одна def set (name,item,iter_stop,lock), а вторая def start (), без аргументов. Процессы я так понимаю должны вызываться через функцию start, все делается через использование value, process,lock из мультипроцессинга(((( Вот загвоздка у меня в переменной iter_stop и как сделать ссылку из функции старт на функцию set, как прописать в Process функцию start если она без аргументов...

Comment: Хорошо. давайте попробуем разобраться. Про set известно содержимое параметров? Процесс запускаем один или сколько-то?

Comment: Процессов несколько, в процесс передать начало и конец каждой игры, это игроки играют в игру.

Comment: если всем начало и конец, то как они поймут, что выполнять? они же все всё и выведут?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что процессов столько же, сколько игроков. В каждый из процессов передать начало и конец игры. Также нужно создать переменную доступную для всех процессов (from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Lock, обратите внимание на импорт........), вывод функции set выглядит так print(name, current_step)

Comment: почти всё понятно. что такое item в set?

Comment: Аргументы для set: name, current_step, iter_stop, process_lock):

Comment: Если current_step, то для каждого шага надо свой процесс запускать. На лету менять аргументы нельзя. Ушел от компа